# Perforce Helix Core: is there a trigger for permissions change?

Tags: perforce

Writing a permissions configurator for the Perforce Helix Core - a separate web application to set up user permissions.

Would like to have a trigger which fire every time user permissions were changed. Does this kind of trigger exist in Helix Core?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a `form-in` trigger with `formname` "protect". Here's an example: http://maillist.perforce.com/pipermail/perforce-user/2004-October/049616.html